# Are the apps shown as 'Installed' in Software Center's 'Installation Status' tab user specific?

Tags: windows, sccm

I'm just starting at a new company and am unfamiliar with Software Center & SCCM. My trainer couldn't definitively answer this question for me.

When I'm logged into a company workstation and open Software Center, there are a list applications shown as 'Installed' in the Installation Status tab. Are these apps all of the installed apps on this workstation, or are these *only* the apps to which I have a license/permissions to use?

And, if this stack is not the 'right' place to ask this question, I'd like to know which one is a better fit.

**Are the apps shown as 'Installed' in Software Center's 'Installation Status' tab user specific?**

Answer (score 1):

```
Are these apps all of the installed apps on this workstation,
```

These are applications that are available via SCCM. There could be many more installed but not available via SCCM. Just Check "Settings" -> "Apps" on our Windows device to list all of the installed applications.

```
or are these only the apps to which I have a license/permissions to use?
```

It depends on your company policy. To be sure, it would be best to talk with your IT-Department about this. For example, we have a special tool for getting permission to use licensed software in our company. Only after you get permission, the software appears in Software Center. Freeware/OpenSource is available for everbody. I have seen companys that are using the software approval in Softwarecenter for licensed Software. Another company has detailed descriptions within the application in Softwarecenter about prices per month, additional needed rights, etc.

```
Are the apps shown as 'Installed' in Software Center's 'Installation Status' tab user specific?
```

This depends on the type of software. If the software is installed System-wide any User on the Device should see it as installed.
If the Software is installed in User-Context, every User should see the state for his own useraccount. But it heavily depends on how the Application gets detected via SCCM.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!! So you're basically saying that the only sure thing is that the applications I see in Software Center are the ones I have available in the current user profile. Hopefully you'll get upvotes to confirm your answer, or someone else will add more information.